# Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected and } expected

Tags: c#

Getting Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected and } expected.
I have tried looking the problem up online but aint getting any smarter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _2_2_digital_vackarklocka
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine(" ╔══════════════════════════════════════╗ ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ║           Väckarklockan              ║ ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ╚══════════════════════════════════════╝ ");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine();


            AlarmClock time = new AlarmClock(13, 24, 7, 35);

            Console.WriteLine(time);      // Tells me that } is expected


            static void Run(AlarmClock ac, int minutes)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}    // Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Comment: Run Method should be removed

Comment: Do not try to declare one method inside another. Perhaps the error message could have been more helpful in this case, but it is a general message saying that the text that has been given does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a method inside another one, which isn't possible. Give it a place for it's own:

```
namespace _2_2_digital_vackarklocka
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine(" ╔══════════════════════════════════════╗ ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ║           Väckarklockan              ║ ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ╚══════════════════════════════════════╝ ");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine();


                AlarmClock time = new AlarmClock(13, 24, 7, 35);

                Console.WriteLine(time);
                // Tells me that } is expected
                // True, there should be one here to close the Main method
        }


        static void Run(AlarmClock ac, int minutes)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your Run method outside the Main method.

Answer (score 1):

You are having a function(run) inside another(main). Put that function outside main. Following one

```
 static void Run(AlarmClock ac, int minutes)
            {

            }
```

This will solve the error.